# How i get the value selected in 'react-native-select-dropdown'?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, variables, select, dropdown

In the react native code below, after i select a country in
react-native-select-dropdown library, how i get the value selected and save it in a variable?

```
`import SelectDropdown from 'react-native-select-dropdown'
const countries = ["Egypt", "Canada", "Australia", "Ireland"]

   <SelectDropdown
   data={countries}
   onSelect={(selectedItem, index) => {
   console.log(selectedItem, index)
}}
   buttonTextAfterSelection={(selectedItem, index) => {
   after item is selected
   return selectedItem
}}
  rowTextForSelection={(item, index) => {       
  return item
}}
/>`
```

All i want after i select a country is save it in a variable.

Answer (score -1):

set up a state variable to store the selected value, when the user selects a country, you can update the state variable:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SelectDropdown from 'react-native-select-dropdown';

const countries = ["Egypt", "Canada", "Australia", "Ireland"];

const App = () => {
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState(null);

  const handleCountrySelect = (selectedItem, index) => {
    setSelectedCountry(selectedItem);
  };

  return (
    <SelectDropdown
      data={countries}
      onSelect={handleCountrySelect}
      buttonTextAfterSelection={(selectedItem, index) => selectedItem}
      rowTextForSelection={(item, index) => item}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```